# Get longitude and latitude with degree sign

Tags: java, formatting, coordinates

how can i get longitude and latitude in degree sign like this
`40°42′51″`

```
lattude = Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
txt5.setText(lattude);
```

that's my code but it show this : `40.4251`

Comment: code formatted, android tag removed other tags added

Answer (score 0):

`Location.convert` returns a string containing double-parts according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert(java.lang.String)) so there is no degree sign at the end.

If you want further formatting you could split your double up by using muliply, modulo and `(int)` conversion (to get the integer part of your split-doubles) and assign proper units to the splits you've gained. Here's a messy quick draft:

```
double test = Double.parseDouble("40.4251d");
System.out.print((int)test + "°");
System.out.print(((int)(test * 100) % 100) + "'" );
System.out.print(((int)(test * 10000) % 100) + "''" );

Output: 40°42'51''
```

You could also play with the flags Location.FORMAT_DEGREES, Location.FORMAT_MINUTES and `Location.FORMAT_SECONDS`but you'd still have to get rid of the format seperators within the given conversion result.

Hope this helps!